# Keep getting 'Object is not a function' error

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, react-redux, redux-thunk

I keep getting an error 'Object is not a function ...' in for my Main.js file. How can it be fixed and what I'm doing wrong? Here is the screenshot of the error:[image]. Also here is my code for my Main.js file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, Image, View, Vibrate } from 'react-native';

import Settings from './Settings';
import Profile from './Profile';

import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {saveProfile, saveSettings} from '../redux/actions';

class Main extends React.Component {

  componentWillMount() {
        if (!this.props.avatarUrl) {
            this.props.saveProfile(this.props.location);
        }
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container, bgColor}>
        <Image
          source={this.props.avatarUrl}
          style={{width: 300, height: 300}}
        />
        <Text>{this.props.name}</Text>
        <Text>{this.props.phone}</Text>
        <Text>{this.props.email}</Text>
        <Settings />
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});

export default saveProfile (
  connect(
    state=>state.location,
    {saveProfile}
  )
)(Main);
```

My goal is to display the information saved in redux.

Comment: Have you tried instead `connect( state=>state.location, {saveProfile} )(saveProfile (Main))`?

Comment: It gives out Syntax error `SyntaxError: /Users/arina/Desktop/mobapp/comps/Main.js: Unexpected token, expected "," (47:20)`

Comment: Can you show us what `saveProfile` is? It should a function to map dispatch functions to props

Comment: Here is safeProfile function:
`export function saveProfile(state = yourProfile, action) {
  let obj = Object.assign({}, state);
  
  switch (action.type) {
    case "SAVE_PROFILE":
      obj.name = action.name;
      return obj;
      
      obj.phone = action.phone;
      return obj;
      
      obj.email = action.email;
      return obj;
      
      obj.avatarUrl = action.avatarUrl;
      return obj;
      
    default:
      return state;
  }
}`

Comment: In your connect(...) please replace `{saveProfile}` with `null`. Will it compile now?

Comment: Still the same.

Comment: Remove the saveProfile in it as well, so `export default connect(
    state=>state.location,
    null
  )(Main)`

Comment: `console.error: "mapStateToProps() in Connect(Main) must return a plain object. Instead received undentified"`

Comment: in that case you can leave out the second parameter and just `connect( state=>state.location)(Main)`

Comment: Still the same error((( I followed the example closely, but still unable to make the app work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your problem is the way you are exporting your main module and the way you connect redux to make uses of the props, I give you the following example to give you an idea of ​​the use of redux...
`

actions.js

```
import * as ACTIONS from './types';

export const reset = () => {
  return { type: ACTIONS.RESET_STATE };
};

export const saveProfile = profile => {
  return { type: ACTIONS.SAVE_PROFILE, payload: profile };
};

export const saveSettings = settings => {
  return { type: ACTIONS.SAVE_SETTINGS, payload: settings };
};
```

reducer.js

```
import * as ACTIONS from './../actions/types';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  profile: 0,
  settings: 0
};

export default (state = INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ACTIONS.RESET_STATE:
      return { ...INITIAL_STATE };
    case ACTIONS.SAVE_PROFILE:
      return { ...state, profile: action.profile };
    case ACTIONS.SAVE_SETTINGS:
      return { ...state, settings: action.settings };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

index.js /combinereducers

```
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';

import reducers from './reducer.js';

export default combineReducers({
  reducer: reducers
});
```

and usage into you Main class

```
import { saveProfile, saveSettings } from './../redux/actions/index.js';

class Main extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      saveProfile: this.props.profile,
      saveSettings: this.props.settings
    };
{.....



.....}

const mapStateToProps = ({ reducers }) => {
  const { profile, settings } = reducers;

  return { profile, settings };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, { saveProfile, saveSettings })(Main);
```

I hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the error is coming from your export default statement at the bottom.  This particular export looks like it may have a syntax error, so double-check how that's structured in the example you're using.

Comment: I've followed the example as it is, but it's not working for me properly.